# subtlety in English expression

Tags: american-english

From time to time I have a feeling that even though I understand each word of a sentence, it's not what i thought it to be.

Example: I watched the 1997 movie "Ice storm", Philip Edwards said of Elena Hood, "Perhaps you find in books what I try to find in people.", Elena took it slightly as an insult, why so? I failed to read between the lines of what Edwards said.

The context was that Edwards was some kind of member of an congregation while Elena stopped going there and they just bumped into each other in some book sale event and started to have some casual chats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is no different from any other language in that a line like that depends heavily on the context of the scene — the personality of the characters, their relationship, the surrounding dialogue, and the tone in which it is spoken.

By implying that Hood prefers books to people, Edwards could be saying that Hood is antisocial:

> [***antisocial***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antisocial) (adj): unwilling or unable to associate in a normal or friendly way with other people.

While "antisocial" is a negative, it's not a *strong* negative, and so, again, the connotation is more about context than comprehension.

Comment: i believe this is the right answer, thanks Andrew.